# DSL through pppoeconf works but through Network Manager stops some sites from loading in browsers?

Tags: internet, network-manager, pppoe, dnsmasq, dsl

I am having Ubuntu 12.04.

DSL through pppoeconf(connecting at boot time) works without any problem but connecting through Network Manager stops some sites from (fully)loading in browsers ?

Disabling dnsmasq by commenting `dns=dsnmasq` line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NeworkManager.conf` is not solving the problem..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not ubuntu problem. It's called MTU (maximum transmission unit). MTU is very sensitive for pppoe connection. I am having same problem, not in ubuntu but my router. I am still looking for answer .

Comment: @shantanu Yes, it's a widely known issue and is caused by a wrong path-MTU. Setting the right MTU at your side should not cause issues, but I've seen b0rked configurations at the ISP side. To solve this for TCP at your end you can use MSS clamping. See http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html

Comment: Have a look at [Why can I not access imgur.com and gravatar.com from Ubuntu but can do so from Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/239921/88802) and check if you have similar symptoms.