# Ubuntu SSH & HTTPS Connection Issues after OS update

Tags: 14.04, ssh, openssh, https

So yesterday everything was working great. My Ubuntu 14.04 was updated with linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85.129 update.

When I start the computer this morning, I noticed that I can no longer SSH to my Bitbucket repository, the MySQL Workbench can't connect to remote servers and even web browsers are giving me Request Timeout when connecting to HTTPS.

I removed and reinstalled openssh-server and still no luck. Not sure where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/312183/527841

My router MTU was set to 1500. After changing the MTU to 1476, everything was great again.